# VSCode debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

If I run and try to debug program in C in VSCode and get this comment:
The program 'C:\vscode\project\build\my_executable.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
Does it mean that the program run without any problem?

thanks

Comment: Yes, it means that your program closed normally. Try putting a breakpoint somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

"Code 0" is the code you pass to the `return` statement when returning from `main` (like `return 0;`), or to `exit` function (like `exit(0);`) if your program exits this way. Normally, return code of 0 indeed means that the program successfully finished.

Try returning some other value, like e.g. `123`, and you should see VSCode telling you that the program exited with code 123 (0x0000007b). Note though that a non-zero exit code usually means unsuccessful termination (i.e. indicating that an error occurred during execution).